# Multiple values with a name in custom variable

Tags: google-analytics

How can i associate multiple values with a name in custom variable??

value—The value for the custom variable. Required. This is a string that is paired with a name. You can pair a number of values with a custom variable name. The value appears in the table list of the UI for a selected variable name. Typically, you will have two or more values for a given name. For example, you might define a custom variable name gender and supply male and female as two possible values.

This is what i read from google analytics.
I want to ask that if i can do something like this

```
 _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',1,'gender','male',2]);
  _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',1,'gender','female',2]);
```

If this is not the right way to achieve what google analytics says then how will achieve my goal to assign more than one value to a name.

Comment: Can you give a specific example of what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Only way to do it is to assign the custom variable and trigger an event or page view for each value.